# Are there any mantras that does not need any guru initiation but gives siddhi?

Tags: mantras, siddhi

Do all mantras that gives siddhi needs guru initiation? Or are there any mantras that can give siddhi without the need of guru?

Comment: Every siddhi can be attained without a guru.

Comment: Not a single Siddhi can be attained without Guru.. All these things come only through Guru Parampara in Hinduism. The real things are not taught in the scriptures. @Wikash_

Comment: The real things are taught in scriptures hence the popularity for scriptures such as the bg.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, except the mantras like "Hare Rama, Hare Krishna" or "Om Namo Narayana" given by saints like Chaitnaya Mahaprabhu, Ramanujacharya to entire mankind, all other mantras need initiation, even if they are simple Gayatri Mantra or "Om".

[Raman Maharshi](https://www.sriramanamaharshi.org/teachings/%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%93/)

> D: “Can anyone get any benefit by repeating sacred syllables (mantras)
>   picked up casually?
>
> M.: “No. He must be competent and initiated in such mantras.” Maharshi
>   illustrated this by the following story: A King visited his Premier in
>   his residence. There he was told that the Premier was engaged in
>   repetition of sacred syllables. The King waited for him and, on
>   meeting him, asked what the words were. The Premier said that it was
>   the holiest of all, Gayatri. The King desired to be initiated by the
>   Premier. But the Premier confessed his inability to initiate him.
>   Therefore the King learned it from someone else, and meeting the
>   Minister later he repeated the Gayatri and wanted to know if it was
>   right. The Minister said that the mantra was correct, but it was not
>   proper for him to say it. When pressed for an explanation, the
>   Minister called to a page close by and ordered him to take hold of the
>   King. The order was not obeyed. The order was often repeated, and
>   still not obeyed. The King flew into a rage and ordered the same man
>   to hold the Minister, and it was immediately done. The Minister
>   laughed and said that the incident was the explanation required by the
>   King. “How?” asked the King. The Minister replied, **“The order was the
>   same and the executor also, but the authority was different. When I
>   ordered, the effect was nil, whereas, when you ordered, there was
>   immediate effect. Similarly with mantras.**”

Comment: why? There has to be some sort of reason.